# When the weight of model get updated if I am using adam optimization?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, keras, deep-learning

I know when the weight of model updated while using gradient descent(in all three types of GD) but in my case I am using adam optimization with custom loss(triplet loss), when the weight get updated in the model in this case? Is it after every sample,every batch or every epochs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Adam just changes how the gradient update is performed in gradient descent, it does not change when that happens, so its literally the same as in normal gradient descent.

When using mini-batch gradient descent (the current standard), weight updates happen after every batch.